# Cannot connect to WIFI with password with non english characters

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords

so I changed my WIFI password, and now it contains the letter "ñ" (from Spanish). The problem is that I can connect from my phone but not from my Windows 10 laptop, as it keeps telling me "wrong password".

Do I need to change some seeting in my laptop, or should I change my WIFI password and avoid non-english characters? Thank you very much.

Comment: Change the password and be done.

Comment: Modern WiFi gear supports Unicode flawlessly. Are you sure you're typing the exact same password as on your phone?

Comment: Having non-ASCII characters in passwords is asking for trouble... and evidently you've got one.

Comment: Thnx for the comments. I just switched ñ witn n to avoid trouble. Mi laptop is a bit old, so I will just avoid the trouble